# Redirecting Output of Non-Child Descendants?

Tags: c#

I want to read the output of UDK.exe, unfortunately it seems to create a child process which has all the goodies in it.

If I redirect the stdout and stdin streams then run UDK.exe, nothing shows up in the console it spawns (udk.exe) and yet I can't read anything from it.  If I don't redirect the streams (either of them, if i redirect a single one I see nothing) then I can see the output in the child process.

In other words (by console I mean the child process thats created):

- set redirect of stdout to true and stderr to false, spawned console
  is empty
- set redirect of stderr to true and stdout to false,
  spawned console is empty
- set both to false, console contains text

If I simply replace UDK.exe with UDK.com in my code, and change no other code, it works 100% - telling me my general code is fine ([link to code](http://pastebin.com/AmwQaGuq)). Unfortunately, for some reason, when I close UDK.com it closes all other instances which were run using udk.exe - which is unacceptable.

I could use some suggestions :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".